# AMP: Analytics Session Linking without breaking Cache

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

As per [this guide](https://blog.amp.dev/2018/09/17/measuring-user-journeys-across-the-amp-cache-and-your-website/) we've implemented AMP Linker to join Google Analytics Sessions when users convert to our non-AMP page. The way I understand this works is by appending the AMP session id to the requested page's query parameters.

Unfortunately this breaks the cache behaviour of our CDN (AWS Cloudfront). Cloudfront currently only allows whitelisting of query parameters for the cache key, blacklisting is not possible.

My first idea was that maybe a `#hash-link` could be used, which I assume can be parsed client-side the same way thata query parameter can be parsed. I don't know how it would behave when switching browsers though (e.g. opening a link in the Google app).

So my question is: Is there a way to implement session linking without breaking cache behaviour on the non-AMP page?